# How to pass a variable from C# (inline) to HTML

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, inline

Sorry in advavce if I use the wrong terminology.
I've got a webpage passing several variables to another page. I'm doing this by declaring variables like so on the first page:

```
Session["unit"] = DropDownList1.Text
```

At the beginning of that second page, I've got some inline C# code (inside `<% %>`) declaring the variables. Now, my problem is that I can't figure out how to access those variables within the html/aspx code.
I think the problem might be compounded because what I'm trying to do is make an SQL SELECT statement string variable within my C# inline code, and then use that SELECT statement within the html/aspx to populate a table...

I've tried, within the html code, doing `<%Response.Write(myVariable)%>` but that's not working for me.

So at the beginning of my code I have:

```
<% string myVariable = (string)Session["unit"];
   string selectStatement = "SELECT unitCode, name, year FROM units WHERE 
   unitCode = '" + myVariable + '";
%>
```

And then further on, I have an `<asp:SqlDataSource>` statement with

```
SelectCommand="<%Response.Write(selectStatement)%>"
```

Thankyou in advance - let me know if I can provide anymore details :-)

Comment: Are you using .NET MVC framework?.

Comment: Nope - just normal web forms I'm pretty sure :-)

Comment: The most important part is that you explain how your 1st webpage is "passing several variables to another page". If we don't know that, we don't know how to retrieve them.

Comment: Sorry about that - I'm using 'Session' to pass them - I've added that bit of code to my explanation.

Comment: You should do `SelectCommand="<%selectStatement%>`